# "Зажав нос" - значение фразеологизма

Tags: семантика

Сейчас в речи русских американцев и переводах (с "американского" же) часто проскакивает *"зажав нос [пойду голосовать за...]"*.

Вопрос такой. Что именно означает употребленный фразеологизм в русском восприятии - и нет ли более точного?

Comment: Неужели что-то непонятно в этом выражении? По-русски звучит вполне нормально, имхо. Не говорить же про выборы "скрепя сердце" или "стиснув зубы".

Comment: Вы ответьте, пожалуйста, что оно значит. Если вам все понятно.

Comment: Амбре-с. It stinks. Политика грязное дело, а не институт благородных девиц.

Comment: Ну вот нет такого значения. Во всяком случае совсем не главное. И политика там вообще не важна. Ладно, на самом деле я и ожидала, что по-русски это звучит совсем не так, как мыслили авторы и переводчики.

Comment: Ну хорошо. Тогда эта... За которую надо голосовать. Она вся такая цветущая, что от неё аллергия и насморк. А Ваша версия?

Comment: Опять мимо. Очень далеко от "американского" смысла. Спасибо.

Comment: А какое исходное английское выражение? Можно догадываться, что здесь переведено буквально, но такие внешне похожие выражения как напр. _to hold one's nose_ и _to thumb one's nose at smth._ различаются по смыслу (преодолевая отвращение, делать vs. воротить нос и избегать).

Comment: *А какое исходное английское выражение?* - если сейчас начать рассуждать об первоисточнике, вопрос потеряет смысл. Да, переведено буквально с *to hold one's nose*, Но чтобы понять, насколько правилен буквальный перевод, надо разобраться прежде всего с тем, что оно значит по-русски.

Comment: Кажется, это — то самое... Цитата из новостей ria.ru: Все счастливые от свершившейся "справедливости" побегут с соплями голосовать за Сандерса и Трамп проиграет.

Comment: @shampar, НЕТ. Нету того самого. В принципе. Есть желание понять, что думают носители русского языка об этой конструкции независимо от источника. Если бы мне нужен был перевод, ч бы так и спросила.

Comment: Зря правку мою убрали: в Вопросе была опечатка, она же и осталась.

Comment: @shampar, дело не в опечатке, а в том, что вы не поняли вопроса. Опечатку я бы не стала откатывать. Вы кавычки убрали. А они там нужны.

Comment: Не унывайте, должен же быть кто поймёт..

Comment: Ирина, я вам чуть позже отвечу, вопрос интересный. Уточните, вас именно восприятие носителями интересует, проблема перевода - за скобками?

Comment: @Morkovkin, ну да. Понимаете, если начать спорить о том, что оно значит в английском, пропадает само понятие адекватного перевода. мы на основании английской семантики начнем выводить семантику русскую. А надо бы наоборот. Сначала независимо оценить, как это звучит в русском - и только потом сравнивать, насколько значения совпадают.

Comment: Еще воображение рисует жителей Бруклина, которых хватают за шнобели и таким способом буксируют к избирательным урнам.

Comment: Вообще вы подали интересную идею графики к их выборам. Четыре обезьяны: три известные плюс четвёртая, зажимающая нос.

Comment: Я забыл про свое обещание, вот сейчас вспомнил. Ваш ответ меня совсем запутал. Если вы хотите сопоставить значения, то как можно это делать без английского? А если только русское значение, то при чем тут английский вообще?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ: в контексте примера, приведённого автором вопроса, "зажав нос" воспринимается как демонстративное  выражение брезгливости.

При отсутствии дополнительных примеров и пояснений от автора, других вариантов нет. "Вы все неправы" не является дополнительной информацией.

Answer (score 0):

Ну как можно говорить о **более точном переводе**, не зная оригинала? 
Если это "to hold one's nose", то значение, конечно, идиоматическое, прямой перевод невозможен.

Я думаю, что "зажав нос" в американском восприятии примерно соответствует нашему выражению "против себя", "без всякого желания", "из-под палки". Не "брезгливости".

А в русском - это именно так, брезгливость (как составляющая). Поэтому перевод не слишком удачен.

К сожалению, развить мысль не могу, не получил реальной информации о том, как вы конкретно вопрос ставите.